# 2010: attach URL parameters to the base url of the iframe

Tags: 2010, iframe, query-string

I have an iframe in my page which has the URL http://example.com/test.aspx?ItemID=n. I want the iframe in my page to load the item id in the query string so that the URL inside the src becomes http://example.com/sample.aspx&ItemID=n. How can this be achieved?